# Confused about behavior on Option between single-level and nested for comprehension

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala so please bear with me. 
I'm confused about the behaviors below:

```
val l = List(Option(1))
for (i <- l; x <- i) yield x //Example 1: gives me List(1)
for(x <- Option(1)) yield x //Example 2: gives me Some(1)
```

Why doesn't the second for comprehension give me `1` instead? Because that would look more consistent to me, intuitively, since the second for comprehension in the first example `x <- i` looks like it should behave exactly the same way as the second example, as the second example basically has extracted the option out of the list to begin with.

Comment: For the return value to be `1` the return type would have to be `Int`, and that type has no way of representing the failure case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put, for comprehension wraps into the type that was used the first time.

```
for (x <- Option(1)) yield x // Returns Option
for (x <- List(1)) yield x   // Returns List
for (x <- Array(1)) yield x  // Returns Array
```

This:

```
for (i <- List(Some(1)); x <- i) yield x
```

Desugares into this:

```
List(Some(1)).flatMap { case i => i.map { case x => x } }
```

`flatMap` of `List` returns `List[T]`, that's why it behaves like that